# How do I pass data from a child window to a parent window on a different thread?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am new to WPF and VB.NET.  I have a parent window that opens a child window. The child is called on a new thread.  My parent can push and pull data from the child using the child's public properties and the dispatcher.  What I can't seem to figure out is how the child can signal the parent to pull fresh data.  I found a [tutorial for C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548131/Transferring-information-between-two-forms-Part-2) and can't seem to make it work in VB.NET.  When I raise my event in the child, the program hangs.  I think it is stuck on the Get in the child.  Can someone show me what I'm missing or need to do?

Below is the VB.NET for my Parent Window:

```
Public Class MainWindow
    Private MyWin As Window1

    Private Sub BtnOpenWindow1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BtnOpenWindow1.Click
        Dim newWindowThread = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadStartingPoint)
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = True
        newWindowThread.Start()
        btnSendData.IsEnabled = True
        BtnRequestData.IsEnabled = True
        BtnOpenWindow1.IsEnabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadStartingPoint(e As EventArgs)
        MyWin = New Window1
        'MyWin.MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyWinDataAvailable);
        AddHandler MyWin.MyEvent, AddressOf MyWinDataAvailable
        MyWin.Show()
        Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyWinDataAvailable(sender As Object)
        tbMainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                                           tbMainWindow.Text = MyWin.MyData
                                       End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSendData_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSendData.Click
        'Send data from MainWindow to the Window1 named MyWin
        MyWin.MyData = tbMainWindow.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRequestData_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BtnRequestData.Click
        'Grab data from Window1
        tbMainWindow.Text = MyWin.MyData
    End Sub

End Class
```

Below is the VB.NET for my child window:

```
Public Class Window1
    Public Property MyData As String
        Get
            Return tbWindow1.Dispatcher.Invoke(Function()
                                                   Return tbWindow1.Text
                                               End Function)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            'The caller sends value using: Wind
            'This calls the Dispatcher of txtValue to schedule the change
            tbWindow1.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                                            tbWindow1.Text = value
                                        End Sub)
        End Set
    End Property

    'Declare an event trigger named MyEvent
    Public Event MyEvent(num As Integer)

    Public Sub Window1DataIsAvailable(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent MyEvent(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSendData1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSendData1.Click
        Window1DataIsAvailable(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Since you're new to both WPF and VB.NET, you may consider using C# instead. There are far more resources available for C# than for VB.NET and C# isn't more difficult to learn than C#.

Comment: Did you use an AI such as ChatGPT to write this code?

Comment: Yes, there are far more examples of WPF in C#.  Seems most people want to code that way. I prefer the blocky look of VB.NET.  VB.NET is easier to for me to read.  I programmed in C years ago. My recent experience has been with VBA so I thought VB.NET would give me a head start.

Comment: Could you send a link to a ChatGPT that could write this code?  I'm curious.  I think the problem I have is RaiseEvent is syncronous so locks the code until the event is handled... and my event handler is running on a different class in a different thread so the event doesn't get cleared?

Comment: Several recommendations:  #. Use one thread for UI. Single window apps. Most of the enterprise size apps I worked on were single window. Learn mvvm and viewmodel first navigation.

Comment: I posted sample code to figure out how to do multi-thread multi-window data sharing.  My final app will have windows that control machinery, communicate with a remote Data Aquisition System, store data about every 1 to 10 seconds, and show real-time data charts....I considered a single thread and making asynchronous calls and thought multi-threading would be a better way of preventing lag.

Comment: I've seen references to MVVM and it seemed like it would take a lot of time for me to learn.  Can you do MVVM in VB.NET?  Ugh... If there is hope I can use VB.NET I'd prefer it... if there is no hope I could switch to C# but it may delay my project due to my learning curve.

Comment: Your window classes must extend `Window`. I assume that this error just happened when you created the example for your question. Otherwise, your code won't work. In addition, the event handlers don't match the event delegate. The `Thread` callback has the wrong signature too and fully qualified types are wrong as well. Your code won't even compile!  

Please be more careful when posting code that needs a review to solve a problem.

Comment: Parameter types mismatch. that's really sloppy code. How can we review this?

Comment: I would keep one thread for UI. A viewmodel per view can spi up a models to handle data processing or collection on separate threads. Binding can marshall data to UI threads via notify property change. F necessary you could batch up data change somewhat so the UI isn't a blur.

Comment: _My recent experience has been with VBA so I thought VB.NET would give me a head start_:  Maybe, maybe not. You may consider spending some time, perhaps an hour, searching for information for _WPF/VB.NET_ and then likewise for _WPF/C#_ before making your decision.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for WPF that I used and found the concepts easy to understand/follow: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLI-F7ydFjNpC2lJ6UI-ZA2FnwR3fiP1IZ . You may consider watching them prior to beginning any programming in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Some considerations:

- First question is: why do you create a second dispatcher thread? This is rarely a good idea. I don't think your scenario qualifies for a second dispatcher thread. Using multiple dispatcher threads is expensive and comes with a lot of overhead and potential pitfalls/bugs, especially in STA frameworks like WPF, where objects have thread affinity.
- The heavy use of the `Dispatcher` - all over the place also requires some refactoring. The `Dispatcher` is only needed if you have to access a `DispatcherObject` (e.g. a `Control` or `Window`) from a different thread.
  You don't sprinkle `Dispatcher` invocations randomly across your code. If a class doesn't access any `DispatcherObject` instances from a different dispatcher thread then it must not use the `Dispatcher`.
  Instead move `Dispatcher` invocations to the actual class that performs the cross-thread referencing.
  In your particular case, all `Dispatcher` invocations must take place in the `MainWindow`. And those invocations must not be by property setters. Otherwise, you won't be able to use the properties from the same dispatcher thread without having the now redundant `Dispatcher` invocations.
- The way you define event delegates is also not following recommended best practices.
  The recommended event pattern is to define event delegates that define the sender of type `object` and the event data object of type `EventArgs` as parameters:

  ```
  ' Let MyEventEventArgs extend EventArgs
  Delegate Sub MyEventDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MyEventEventArgs)
  ```

  It's recommended to use the predefined delegates `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<T>` whenever possible:

  ```
  Public Event MyEvent As EventHandler(Of MyEventEventArgs)
  ```
- The way you handle the dispatcher thread is not correct. First of all, it must be a foreground thread and not a background thread. Then you must manually shutdown the dispatcher once the `Window` is closed. Or you must keep the thread alive and reuse it.
  Shutting down the dispatcher queue is normally done by the `Application` class that owns the primary dispatcher thread. In your case, when you create a secondary dispatcher thread you must also take care of its lifetime and call `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdownutDown` at some point.

  And speaking of the thread's lifetime, currently you are creating a new dispatcher thread *every time* the button is clicked.
  Since the dispatcher thread must be a foreground thread you must also stop it to free its resources.

  In other words, either create new `Window1` instances on the *same* thread after a `Window1` instance was closed (requires to store the thread reference in a field). Or handle the `Window.Closed` event to manually shutdown the dispatcher queue by calling `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdownutDown` and then also stop the thread by calling `Thead.Abort`.
- To exchange data between classes, consider introducing a data structure to carry the payload.
  Don't reference the classes properties to set its new data values. This requires the updating class to know about internals of the updated class. Instead let the updating class call a e.g. `Update` method on the updated class and pass in a data structure that carries all the data you want to exchanged.
- Then decide whether you want to receive data via event or via direct instance access. Using both doesn't make sense. You currently have a `Button.Click` handler that reads data from the `Window1` instance and in addition an event that you observe. Use one or the other. I recommend using event based communication (at least for your current unidirectional communication).

  For example, let `MainWindow` observe `Window1` events to get data (or `Window1` to send data) and use dedicated update methods like `Window1.SetData` to send data from `MainWindow` to `Window1`.
  If you want to allow `Window1` to explicitly communicate to `MainWindow` e.g. in order to get data, then `Window1` would need a reference to `MainWindow`.

Although **I recommend to not create a new dispatcher thread for the other window**, the following example shows how you should handle this thread and also gives an example on how you can exchange data between two objects:

**MainWindow.xaml.vb**

```
Public Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Public Property TextData As String
        Get
            Return CStr(GetValue(TextDataProperty))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Return SetValue(TextDataProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly TextDataProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextData", GetType(String), GetType(MainWindow), New PropertyMetadata("default"))

    Private myWin As Window1
    Private newWindowThread As Thraed

    Private Sub BtnOpenWindow1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Me.newWindowThread = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadStartingPoint)
        Me.newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)

        ' Because this is new dispatcher thread, this must be a foreground thread!
        Me.newWindowThread.IsBackground = False
        Me.newWindowThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadStartingPoint(ByVal e As Object)
        Me.myWin = New Window1()

        ' We have to manually shutdown the dispatcher or it will continue to run.
        Me.myWin.Closed += AddressOf OnMyWinClosed
        Me.myWin.MyEvent += AddressOf OnMyWinDataAvailable
        Me.myWin.Show()
        Dispatcher.Run()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnMyWinClosed(ByVal sender As Object?, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' You must also shutdown the dispatcher queue. This is normally done by the Application.
        ' But since we are responsible for the new dispatcher thread, we have to take care of it by ourselves.
        '
        ' Using multiple dispatcher threads adds a lot of overhead as you can even see in this very trivial example.
        Me.myWin.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        ' Next end the foreground thread (or reuse it - 
        ' but don't create new threads and keep all the old threads alive)
        Me.newWindowThread.Abort()

        ' Remove the strong reference
        ' to allow the garbage collector to take care of the allocated memory
        Me.myWin = Nothing
    End Sub

    ' Get data via event (recommended)
    Private Sub OnMyWinDataAvailable(ByVal sender As Object?, ByVal e As MyEventEventArgs)
        Dim exchangeData As ExchangeData = e.Data
        Me.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Function() Me.TextData = exchangeData.Text, DispatcherPriority.Background)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSendData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
       ' Because we are on a different dispatcher thread
       ' and accessing another DispatcherObject (the Window1 extends Window)
       ' we must use the Dispatcher of Window1 to reference/manipulate the instance.
       ' This is only required because our manipulation will lead to changes of dependency properties
       ' of controls that belong to a different dispatcher thread.
       '
       ' Using multiple dispatcher threads adds a lot of overhead as you can even see in this very trivial example.
        Dim exchangeData = New ExchangeData(Me.TextData)
        Me.myWin.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Function() Me.myWin.SetData(exchangeData))
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub BtnRequestData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
      ' Grab data from Window1.
      ' Because we are on a different dispatcher thread
      ' and accessing another DispatcherObject (the Window1 extends Window)
      ' we must use the Dispatcher of Window1 to reference the instance.
      ' This is only required because we are accessing dependency properties of a different dispatcher thread.
      '
      ' Using multiple dispatcher threads adds a lot of overhead as you can even see in this very trivial example.
        Dim exchangeData As ExchangeData = Await Me.myWin.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Me.myWin.GetData)
        Me.TextData = exchangeData.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="Root">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Send"
            Click="BtnSendData_Click" />
    <Button Content="Request"
            Click="BtnRequestData_Click" />
    <Button Content="Open Window"
            Click="BtnOpenWindow1_Click" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=TextData}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.vb**

```
Public Partial Class Window1
    Inherits Window

    ' The dependency property for data binding
    Public Property MyData As String
        Get
            Return CStr(GetValue(MyDataProperty))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Return SetValue(MyDataProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly MyDataProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyData", GetType(String), GetType(Window1), New PropertyMetadata("default"))

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    ' Declare an event named MyEvent
    Public Event MyEvent As EventHandler(Of MyEventEventArgs)

    Public Function GetData() As ExchangeData
        Dim eventData = New ExchangeData(Me.MyData)
        Return eventData
    End Function

    Public Sub SetData(ByVal exchangeData As ExchangeData)
        Me.MyData = exchangeData.Text
    End Sub

    ' Declare a NON-PUBLIC! event invocator for the MyEvent event
    Protected Overridable Sub OnMyEvent(ByVal eventData As ExchangeData)
        Me.MyEvent?.Invoke(Me, New MyEventEventArgs(eventData))
    End Sub

    ' Send the TextBox content
    Private Sub BtnSendData1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim eventData As ExchangeData = GetData()

        ' Raise the event to notify listeners that data is available
        OnMyEvent(eventData)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Window1.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="Root">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=MyData}" />
    <Button Content="Send"
            Click="BtnSendData1_Click" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**ExchangeData.vb**

```
' The data structure to consolidate data for exchange
Public Class ExchangeData
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Empty As ExchangeData = New ExchangeData(String.Empty)
    Public ReadOnly Property Text As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub
End Class
```

**MyEventEventArgs.vb**

```
' The custom event args
Public Class MyEventEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Sub New(ByVal data As ExchangeData)
        Me.Data = data
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Data As ExchangeData
End Class
```